# Displaying function dependency graph in iPython Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I frequently use Jupyter notebook for collaborative purposes. Frequently, people write functions within their own modules that call functions from other modules, all of which are part of our library. An example case would be:

module1.f1 -> module2.f2 -> module3.f3 -> pandas functions.

All the functions, f1/f2/f3 follow docstring format. Is there a way to display the function hierarch f1 - f2 -f3 inside the notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use plantuml?
You then choose the UML which gives you something you like ...